# MapReduce job hanging

Tags: java, xml, hadoop, mapreduce

I am quite new to hadoop. Recently installed it and now trying to run my first job (from the tutorial) with the following command

```
bin/hadoop jar share/hadoop/mapreduce/hadoop-mapreduce-examples-2.7.3.jar grep input output 'dfs[a-z.]+'
```

However the job is hanging at a stage

```
16/12/09 12:26:55 INFO client.RMProxy: Connecting to ResourceManager at /0.0.0.0:8032
16/12/09 12:26:56 INFO input.FileInputFormat: Total input paths to process : 0
16/12/09 12:26:56 INFO mapreduce.JobSubmitter: number of splits:0
16/12/09 12:26:56 INFO mapreduce.JobSubmitter: Submitting tokens for job: job_1481239473466_0006
16/12/09 12:26:56 INFO impl.YarnClientImpl: Submitted application application_1481239473466_0006
16/12/09 12:26:56 INFO mapreduce.Job: The url to track the job: http://Emrahs-MacBook-Pro.local:8088/proxy/application_1481239473466_0006/
16/12/09 12:26:56 INFO mapreduce.Job: Running job: job_1481239473466_0006
```

I saw on some similar questions that mapred-site.xml and yarn-site.xml could be relevant. contents of these files are

mapred-site.xml

```
<configuration> 
    <property>   
        <name>mapreduce.framework.name</name>  
        <value>yarn</value>  
    </property>   
    <property>  
        <name>yarn.app.mapreduce.am.resource.mb</name>  
        <value>1228</value>
    </property>
    <property> 
        <name>yarn.app.mapreduce.am.command-opts</name> 
        <value>-Xmx983m</value>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>mapreduce.map.memory.mb</name>
        <value>1228</value>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>mapreduce.reduce.memory.mb</name>
        <value>1228</value>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>mapreduce.map.java.opts</name>
        <value>-Xmx983m</value>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>mapreduce.reduce.java.opts</name>
        <value>-Xmx983m</value>
    </property>
</configuration>
```

yarn-site.xml

```
<configuration>

<!-- Site specific YARN configuration properties -->
    <property>
        <name>yarn.nodemanager.aux-services</name>
        <value>mapreduce_shuffle</value>
    </property>
    <property> 
        <name>yarn.scheduler.minimum-allocation-mb</name> 
        <value>1228</value>
    </property>
    <property> 
        <name>yarn.scheduler.maximum-allocation-mb</name> 
        <value>9830</value>
    </property>
    <property> 
        <name>yarn.nodemanager.resource.memory-mb</name> 
        <value>9830</value>
    </property>
</configuration>
```

I checked on the hadoop dashboard for failing nodes or lack of disk but couldn't see anything wrong.
Any help will be appreciated
Kind regards

Comment: What does yarn logs -applicationId application_1481239473466_0006  show ?

Comment: you run this on the terminal..

Comment: /tmp/logs/emrahozkan/logs/application_1481239473466_0006 does not exist.
Log aggregation has not completed or is not enabled.